# Why in FF audio is playing. But i use paus()?

Tags: javascript, firefox, html5-audio

var audios = document.querySelectorAll('audio');
var audios1 = audios[0];

```
for (var i = 0; i < audios.length; i++) {
var audio = audios[i]
// Stop playing
audio.pause();
audio.currentTime = 0;
audio.setAttribute("type","audio/ogg");
audio.parentNode.removeChild(audio)
```

}

https://prnt.sc/11swa3v

Answer (score 0):

You set attribute `autoplay="autoplay"`, so it starts playback automatically. Try to remove that attribute.

Comment: I tried, not work. Music plaing further to the end. And if start next track, then its playing together at the same time

Comment: Check if your JS is loaded, everything works fine in my fiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/no1lov3sme/g4udf9pz/

Comment: Hi, this link to quiz <a href="staracm8.beget.tech/…> <img src="habrastorage.org/webt/60/8f/c6/608fc678c9606637650466.png" alt="image"/> <img src="habrastorage.org/webt/60/8f/c6/608fc694da969358415762.png" alt="image"/> First screen- start quiz, second screen- button to stop music. Work only in Chrome

Comment: I can't see your link.

Comment: https://screenrec.com/share/DsSRqUQ5OT - video, live - link http://staracm8.beget.tech/index.php?option=com_joomlaquiz&view=quiz&quiz_id=2&force=1&Itemid=108

Comment: Are you using Audio() constructor somewhere in your code?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio

Comment: Only `function myEvents2(){
   var quizblock = document.getElementById('jq_quiz_container_tbl');
    console.log(quizblock);
    const audio = quizblock.getElementsByTagName('audio'); // получаем все элементы аудио

    var active = 0;
    console.log(audio);

    var audio1 = audio[0];
    audio1.setAttribute('type','audio/ogg');
    audio1.pause();
    audio1.currentSrc = '';
    audio1.muted = true;
    audio1.defaultMuted = true;
    audio1.autoplay = false;
    //audio1.outerHTML='';
    console.log(audio1);
   };`